# S3 bucket created with Terraform is not being listed in the console

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am starting with Terraform. I try to create a S3 bucket using this simple code (variables exist but not posted here):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.main_prefix}-${var.resource_prefix}-${var.bucket_prefix}-${substr(var.environment_tag,0,3)}-${var.domains[0]}"
  acl = "public-read"

  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

The problem is that Terraform says it was created ok, updates the state and everything seems to be working perfectly:

```
λ terraform apply

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.bucket will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = "public-read"
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "*****************************"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags                        = {
          + "environment" = "***********"
          + "project"     = "***********"
        }
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

      + versioning {
          + enabled    = (known after apply)
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_s3_bucket.bucket: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket.bucket: Creation complete after 4s [id=**********************************]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

but the bucket is not listed in the S3 console.
I can't create the same bucket using the console afterwards, so it seems Terraform created it:

"Bucket with the same name already exists"

What could I be forgetting or doing wrong?

Comment: You very likely created the bucket in a different account/region than you are viewing in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343387/matt-schuchard) suggested, the bucket was being created in a different account. I explain why so everybody can follow the steps when finding the same issue.

1. I enabled Terraform logging as explained in [their documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html).
2. Analyzing the logs I saw that a different account was being used, not the one I thought.
3. The account being used was configured in the environment variables, not on the [AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-where) as I supposed. Those environment variables where set many months ago for another project. AWS provider for Terraform has a priority order for getting credentials, specified [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication). That is why.[image: AWS provider for Terraform credential's priority]
4. I confirmed that the bucket was being created on the other AWS account, so I called `terraform destroy` to delete the bucket to undo the changes.
5. I removed the environment variables and confirmed the credentials on the credential's file profile where being used this time.
6. Called `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` with the new credentials (after a while, so the bucket name becomes available again for creation) to create the bucket in the correct account.